# Open links from an array without triggering the popup filter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm trying to develop a tool which gets the links from a page, stores them in an array and opens with one click in a new tab. Is there a way to accomplish that without triggering the browser's popup spam filter?

Here's my code:

```
<?php 

    $base = "web.archive.org";
    $time = "/web/20160101000000*/";
    $domain = @$_POST["domain"];

    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "$base$time$domain");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT_MS, 20000); //in miliseconds


    $output = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);



    # REPLACES ALL URLs OF WAYBACK MACHINE
    $replacedHrefHtml = preg_replace('/(href=")/', "href=\"https://web.archive.org", $output);


    # REPLACES ALL SRCs OF WAYBACK MACHINE
    $replacedsrc = preg_replace('/(src=")/', "src=\"https://web.archive.org", $replacedHrefHtml);


    #get wbCalendar

    $html = str_get_html($replacedsrc);
    $elem = $html->find('div[id=wbCalendar]', 0);

    #extract the links and store them into an array
    $data = array();
    $open = '';
    foreach($elem->find('a') as $element) {
           $extracted = $element->href;
           $open .= "window.open('{$extracted}'); ";
           $data[] = $extracted;
    }

    echo "<a href=\"#\" class=\"cd-read-more\" onclick=\"{$open}\" style=\"float:left;\">Open multiple links</a>";
```

?>

You can test it here: seotify.com/archive-opener

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Nope, only windows opened by a user action, i.e. the user actually clicks something, is allowed.

Comment: This is very disturbing for UX. http://i.imgur.com/OXzWfoW.png

Comment: Thanks for the warning, @Adam. Actually, there's a small group of people (including me) that checks more than 100 domains each day on Waybackmachine and we have to open thousands of links one by one. 

The process takes 3 - 5 hours a day and just these 50 lines of code will cut this time to the 45 min. However, I think they'll have to remove the popup filter for this site.

Comment: Check those domains for what? Sounds like an XY-problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know there is no way you can ensure the popup filter won't catch you. I think the only thing you can do is to make the windows open in an "on-click" event `someElement.onclick = function(){ /*POPUP CODE*/ }` (so that the code is triggered in response to a user action)